# Why does adding graphql-client as dependency cause rover to break?

Tags: rust, graphql, dependencies, apollo, rust-cargo

I am setting up this [project](https://github.com/apollographql/router/tree/v0.1.0-preview.6/examples/context) to help me pass authorization data between each subgraphs. I have an authorization subgraph to gather the data so the router will have to make a graphql query to the authorization subgraph and then pass it along. I picked `graphql_client` dependency because it's the same one that Apollo uses and it seems to have a lot of support compare to the other Rust graphql clients however when I add this dependency, it breaks another dependency. These are the steps

1. set up context example project -> https://github.com/apollographql/router/tree/v0.1.0-preview.6/examples/context
2. add these as dependency in Cargo.toml

   ```toml
   graphql_client = { version = "0.10.0", features = ["reqwest-blocking"] }
   reqwest = { version = "0.11.10", features = ["blocking"] }
   ```
3. run cargo build
4. see error

```
Compiling launchpad v0.1.0 (https://github.com/apollographql/rover.git?rev=94141242ba34cf00cde9630fc4a6dcd05d4fa5da#94141242)
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `HeaderMap`
  --> /Users/macuser/.cargo/git/checkouts/rover-efd9f422be37a06b/9414124/crates/launchpad/src/introspect/runner.rs:30:26
   |
30 |     let mut header_map = HeaderMap::new();
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
   |
help: consider importing this struct
   |
1  | use reqwest::header::HeaderMap;
   |

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `HeaderName`
  --> /Users/macuser/.cargo/git/checkouts/rover-efd9f422be37a06b/9414124/crates/launchpad/src/introspect/runner.rs:33:13
   |
33 |             HeaderName::from_bytes(header_key.as_bytes())?,
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
   |
help: consider importing this struct
   |
1  | use reqwest::header::HeaderName;
   |

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `HeaderValue`
  --> /Users/macuser/.cargo/git/checkouts/rover-efd9f422be37a06b/9414124/crates/launchpad/src/introspect/runner.rs:34:13
   |
34 |             HeaderValue::from_str(&header_value)?,
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
   |
help: consider importing this struct
   |
1  | use reqwest::header::HeaderValue;
   |

error[E0659]: `reqwest` is ambiguous
 --> /Users/macuser/.cargo/git/checkouts/rover-efd9f422be37a06b/9414124/crates/launchpad/src/introspect/runner.rs:6:5
  |
6 | use reqwest::header::{HeaderMap, HeaderName, HeaderValue};
  |     ^^^^^^^ ambiguous name
  |
  = note: ambiguous because of multiple potential import sources
  = note: `reqwest` could refer to a crate passed with `--extern`
  = help: use `::reqwest` to refer to this crate unambiguously
note: `reqwest` could also refer to the module imported here
 --> /Users/macuser/.cargo/git/checkouts/rover-efd9f422be37a06b/9414124/crates/launchpad/src/introspect/runner.rs:5:5
  |
5 | use graphql_client::*;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  = help: use `self::reqwest` to refer to this module unambiguously
```

Dependency tree is apollo router -> uplink -> rover (branch = geal/launchpad)

Answer (score 1):

I posted this same issue on apollo/router repo and they said it'll be fix soon

https://github.com/apollographql/router/issues/937#issuecomment-1114995491

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your subgraph to receive it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).